# All com.google.android.gms libraries must use exact same version

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have updated compileSdkVersion from 23 to 24. After, it gave me an error for com.google.android.gms. When I checked the library, there is only one com.google.android.gms is in the version of 8.3.0 (measurement).

[image]

I couldn't force to update measurement as

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:9.4.0'
```

It is giving the following error;

> Failed to resolve:
>   com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:9.4.0

I have examined other stackoverflow questions but they couldnt solve my problem.
How can I solve this error?

Here are my dependencies;

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.20.0') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
}

compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.4.0'
compile 'com.github.npanigrahy:Custom-Calendar-View:v1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.0'
compile 'com.wonderpush:wonderpush-android-sdk:1.2.3.2'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
compile 'org.mod4j.org.apache.commons:lang:2.1.0'
compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.2.0'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile project(':circleimageview-release')
```

}

full error text:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
>
> > Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is
> >     available at
> >     https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/)
> >     or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 8.3.0.

Comment: run ./gadlew app:Dependencies to see what libs use what version then you can update your libs accordingly

Comment: also update your libs looking at table1. what is **play-services-measurement** used for. Is this migrated to firebase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have find the solution of my problem. I have updated my project level of my gradle as from

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0-beta2'
```

to

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```